# How to check passenger details from a field is displayed in a drop down?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am struggling to find out a way in order to be able to capture passenger text from a input bar and then use it to check if it's within a drop down menu.

Below is my current idea on retrieving the passengers names. For each passenger there's their own first name and surname fields:

In the page interactions page:

```
    public List<string> GetPassengerNames(By passengerNameType)
    {
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        var myFields = _driver.FindElements(passengerNameType);
        foreach (var myField in myFields)
        {
            myList.Add(myField.Text);
        }
        return myList;
    }
```

in the step definition:

```
    public void ThisIsMyForenameTestStepMethod()
    {
        List<string> myList = GetPassengerNames(PassengerDetailsElements.ForenameField);
        ScenarioContext.Current.Add("ForeNameList", myList);
    }

    public void ThisIsMySurnameTestStepMethod()
    {
        List<string> myList = GetPassengerNames(PassengerDetailsElements.SurnameField);
        ScenarioContext.Current.Add("SurnameList", myList);
    }
```

I want to know the next step from here to be honest. I need to select a drop down and just ensure the options in the drop down match the passenger details but at the same time, I need to make sure the forename and surname for each passengers are correct. It like i need to be able to concatenate the names correctly after retrieving their first and surnames but not sure how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate firstname & surname list in new list as:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
newList.addAll(listOne);
newList.addAll(listTwo);
```

And then validate drop down values match with newList values. If value matches then your validation is successful.

To validate drop down you can use below code:

```
IWebElement comboBox = new WebDriverWait(_browserWindow, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(d => _browserWindow.FindElement(By.Id(id)));
                SelectElement dropdownList = new SelectElement(comboBox);
                int j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < newList.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (dropdownList.Options[i].Text == "")
                    {
                        continue; //if drop down contain 1st value as blank
                    }
                    if (dropdownList.Options[i].Text == newList[j])
                    {
                        j++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Value Matched");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Data not found");
                    }
                }
```

You can change above code as per your need